# How to use Map in BroadcastProcessFunction in scala?

Tags: stream, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to create a rulesource from http endpoint and broadcast that rule and match with each event with the rule and get rule as well as the event.My rule is  of Map[String, String] so how to use that and get it broadcasted.

Below is the class I have defined :

```
import com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.analytics.scalasdk.Event
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.MapStateDescriptor
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.co.BroadcastProcessFunction
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector

class MapFunction extends BroadcastProcessFunction[Event, Map[String, String], (Event, String)] {
  private lazy val ruleBroadcastState =
    new MapStateDescriptor("rules", classOf[String], classOf[String])

  override def processElement(
    value: Event,
    ctx: BroadcastProcessFunction[Event, Map[String, String], (Event, String)]#ReadOnlyContext,
    out: Collector[(Event, String)]
  ): Unit = {
    val state = ctx.getBroadcastState(ruleBroadcastState)
    if (state.contains(value.app_id.getOrElse("unidentified"))) {
      out.collect(value, state.get(value.app_id.getOrElse("unidentified")))
    }
  }

  override def processBroadcastElement(
    rule: Map[String, String],
    ctx: BroadcastProcessFunction[Event, Map[String, String], (Event, String)]#Context,
    out: Collector[(Event, String)]
  ): Unit = {

    val state = ctx.getBroadcastState(ruleBroadcastState)
    state.put("test-123", "test-stream")//this is for testing only actual is the Map iteration
  }
}
```

Here in processBroadcastElement rule is of Map[String, String] so when I put the values in state do I have to iterate each element and put or what I have to do?

Rule is like below:

```
Map("test-123" -> "test-stream", "Original-app-2876" -> "prod-v0-model", "Original-app-2987" -> "prod-v1-model")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the putAll method.

[image]

https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/eb58aa1ab7bdbbcbf07de9726b4c8a81d8e5ab0e/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/state/BroadcastState.java#L54

[image]

org.apache.flink.api.common.state.BroadcastState#putAll

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I am confused how processelement will get this map is it required to iterate over ?

Comment: @KumarPadhy ,sorry, I didn't understand you.the processBroadcastElement() which is responsible for processing incoming elements in the broadcasted stream and the processElement uses the mapState directly.ctx.getBroadcastState(ruleStateDescriptor).immutableEntries() can help you iterate through the map.